# Как извлечь число из строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка, такого вида, мне нужно извлечь из нее число, parseInt не помогает...(

```js
var str = 'mkmkmklmkl[1]';
console.log(parseInt(str));
```

Comment: Вы же уже задавали этот вопрос (*`задан 12 ноя '17 в 8:34`*). Что там вам неясно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = 'mkmkmklrmkl[1]';
console.log(parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)));
```

Выведет только первое попавшееся число.

**UPD:** Существует два способа создания объекта RegExp: литеральная запись и использование конструктора. При записи строк параметры в литеральной записи не используют символы кавычек, в то время как параметры функции-конструктора используют кавычки. Так что следующие выражения создают одинаковые регулярные выражения:

```
/ab+c/i; 
new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');
```

Используйте литеральную запись если регулярное выражение будет неизменным. Например, если вы используете литеральную запись для конструирования регулярного выражения, используемого в цикле, регулярное выражение не будет перекомпилироваться на каждой итерации.

Конструктор объекта регулярного выражения, например, `new RegExp('ab+c')`, обеспечивает компиляцию регулярного выражения во время выполнения. Используйте функцию-конструктор, если вы знаете, что шаблон регулярного выражения будет меняться или если вы не знаете шаблон и получаете его из внешних источников, например, из пользовательского ввода.

Comment: Лучше опустить конструктор, `new RegExp(/\d+/)` => `/\d+/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew вы правы, так тоже работает. Не подскажете где можно почитать про разницу, нашел только то что они не равны при таких вызовах?

Comment: Не знаю, где написано, на основном SO можно поискать. `new RegExp(/\d+/)` не во всех браузерах работает. Конструктор необходим только в тех случаях, когда шаблон задаётся с помощью переменной.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в случае `new RegExp(/\d+/)` параметр _литерал регулярного выражения_ будет просто приведен к строке которая и будет передана в конструктор

Comment: @Grundy Это не во всех браузерах поддерживается.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, вроде бы во всех: стандартный вызов `toString` будет. Можно пример какой-нибудь где не сработает?

Comment: @Grundy IE? Safari?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. в safari нет возможности проверить, в IE даже в 5 (в режиме эмуляции) работает.

Comment: Не знаю, помню, что это как раз недавнее нововведение. В любом случае, лучше использовать литерал, чтобы не было проблем типа [таких](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964916/differences-between-javascript-regexp-literal-and-constructor).